# « Vouer aux gémonies » : Loc. fig., mod., littér. ou iron. ?

Tags: locutions, dictionnaires, connotation

Je lis en éditorial dans [*Le Monde*](https://www.lemonde.fr/idees/article/2023/01/03/la-panne-ideologique-des-republicains-americains_6156439_3232.html) :

> Il [le Parti républicain américain] s’est converti à un populisme
> alimenté par l’anxiété identitaire qui le réduit aujourd’hui à
> dénoncer préventivement toute proposition venant du camp démocrate et
> à **vouer aux gémonies** un progressisme, qualifié uniformément de
> « wokisme », en niant la persistance d’inégalités sociales, à
> commencer par la permanence d’un racisme systémique.

Je ne connaissais pas la locution « vouer aux [gémonies](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/g%C3%A9monies) » signifiant « accabler de mépris, outrager publiquement » et ayant comme synonyme « vilipender » (TLFi). Le TLFi la marque *Loc. fig., mod., littér. ou iron.*, évidemment c'est au figuré, mais « [moderne](http://atilf.atilf.fr/scripts/mep.exe?CRITERE=ABREVIATIONS_M;ISIS=isis_tlfi.txt;MENU=menu_tlfi;OUVRIR_MENU=0;ONGLET=tlfi;OO1=2;ISIS=isis_tlfi.txt) » ? et « littéraire ou ironique » ? Cette présentation mélange l'époque, le registre et la rhétorique et semble les présenter comme des possiblités distinctes...

À quoi fait référence « moderne » dans la vedette ou comment comprendre « *Loc. fig., mod., littér. ou iron.* » et comment ça permettrait de mieux comprendre l'emploi de la locution dans l'extrait ?

Answer (score 1):

En ce qui concerne « mod. », à mon avis, il faut se référer à ce qui est appelé le français moderne, c'est à dire le français tel qu'il est parlé de nos jours.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fran%C3%A7ais))  − [D'un point de vue hist.] Ancien français. Langue française issue du roman et parlée au Moyen Âge. La rainette, raine verte, verdier, en ancien français (Gourmont, Esthét. lang. fr.,1899, p. 190).Moyen français. Langue française parlée à la fin du Moyen Âge et à l'époque de la Renaissance. **Français moderne**. Langue française parlée de nos jours et qui commence à être fixée au xvi<sup>e</sup> siècle.

Si l'on considère une expression comme « aux ides de mars », on voit qu'elle n'est pas très moderne. Elle a connu son essor vers 1750 et a commencé à décliner en 1800.

[image]

Il n'en est pas de même pour « vouer aux gémonies ».

[image]

Cette expression-là ne connait un véritable essor qu'approximativement en 1880, et ne commence à décliner qu'après 2000.

C'est donc une locution qui est utilisée figurativement, dont l'origine de l'usage est relativement récent et que l'on trouve soit dans un contexte littéraire soit ironique. Personnellement, je pense que le contexte ironique est aussi littéraire.

Comment: Cinq siècles ça commence à être long pour une ère je trouve dans le sens où je trouve peu utile cet classification au TLF, je veux dire la mention _moderne_ va-t-elle apparaître à toutes les expressions employées après le 16e ? Peut-être qu'ils auraient dû réserver ça pour la section étymologie... Dans _Le Monde_, tu vois ça comme du même registre que le reste du texte ou pourquoi ne pas avoir utilisé _vilipender_ ?

Comment: @mastödantirâfamî Le xvi<sup>e</sup> siècle n'est que le début de la transformation, le point dans le temps lorsque le langage commence à être fixé. Je ne crois pas qu'il s'agisse d'un point de vue tel que celui que les anglais ont adopté et selon lequel l'anglais moderne s'étend de la période de Shakespeare à nos jours (le lecteur anglais moderne ne comprend pas Shakespeare sans une myriade de notes de bas de page). Non, le français moderne est loin de remonter Jusqu'au xvi<sup>e</sup> siècle. Cent années sont suffisantes pour que déjà des personnes faisant autorité trouvent  (1/3)

Comment: @mastödantirâfamî  certains éléments trop vieux ; dans ce problème  de la délimitation de la langue moderne dans le temps je ne crois pas qu'il faille s'éloigner de plus de cent à cent cinquante ans dans le passé. On peut remarquer que pour l'expression « travailler pour le roi de Prusse », qui a un graphe d'une extension similaire dans le temps (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pour+le+roi+de+Prusse&year_start=1500&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3) il n'y a aucune remarque de cette sorte ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/roi)) ; il est possible néanmoins (2/3)

Comment: @mastödantirâfamî   que la note historique rende cela superflu. Il n'existe rien qui le prouve vraiment, mais  « mod. » aurait pu être  apposé avec l'idée d'opposition au  « A », où on trouve des exemples d'utilisation figurée mais pas après 1859, ce qui ne serait pas vraiment dans le « moderne », tel que je le conçois. Ce mot ne serait plus utilisé autrement depuis, mais ça teste à vérifier. Le registre est le même, littéraire ; pourquoi pas « vilipender »? Peut-être parce que la force de la métaphore avait de l'attrait pour cet auteur.  (3/3)